# Is it possible to add a tooltip when hovering the mouse cursor over the selected element inside input to Autocomplete mui?

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui, autocomplete

Is it possible to add a tooltip when hovering the mouse cursor over the selected element inside the input, provided that the element exceeds the width of the container?

I tried wrapping a `Tooltip` around a `TextField` in the `renderInput` attribute.

On the one hand, it helps, but there are a lot of unnecessary redraws.
Interested in whether it is possible to wrap only the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this by manipulating `getOptionLabel` attribute.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Chip from '@mui/material/Chip';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';

export default function Tags() {
  return (
    <Stack spacing={3} sx={{ width: 500 }}>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-standard"
        options={top100Films}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => (
          <Tooltip title={option.title}>{option.title}</Tooltip>
        )}
        defaultValue={[top100Films[0]]}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="standard"
            label="tooltip"
            placeholder="Favorites"
          />
        )}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
}

const top100Films = [
  { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I also thought about it, but getOptionLabel should return a string according to the documentation, and when I try to output node element, I see errors and incorrect display

Comment: Can you update your question with what have you tried so far and what is the result you got?